# "A count of how many of this item IS in the room", or "A count of how many of this item ARE in the room"

Tags: phrase-usage, singular-vs-plural

Which is correct out of the following?

A count of how many of this item ARE in the room

A count of how many of this item IS in the room

Does the *this item* require the singular *is*?

Comment: In my question the sentence is composed differently so I'm not sure how it applies.

Comment: I’ve edited it to highlight what keeps the OP from being a duplicate.

Comment: "A count of how many…" does not make sense to me. The *main* problem with the examples is not whether the verb should be singular or plural, it's whether it makes meaningful sense.  I have to paraphrase it to be meaningful: **This is the number of items in the room** "How many" is usually for questions, and for (countable) plural nouns. I am therefore voting to close

Comment: @Mari-LouA You have misunderstood the question. We aren't asking how many, we are stating it, and we are not counting items, we are counting "this item". Another example is "Take a count of how many of this card is/are in the deck".

Comment: I'm sorry but where did you see "Take a count" being used in English? You can *"take account of something”* but that means to acknowledge or include something in the equation not to physically count the number of items. Also "…how many of **this card**…” is ungrammatical because "card" is countable., if it's not a request than the answer should be something like: **There are 52 cards** *in this deck* which makes total sense and is grammatical.

Comment: The phrasal verb [take the count](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_the_count) has its own meaning but I have not found the expression *take a count*.

Comment: I've heard the phrase "Take a head count" many times before, but that's besides the point.

Comment: I read the following sentence in a game rule book: "A count of how many of this item are in the game and where this card lies within that count". It looked wrong to me, so I came here to see what others think. It is clumsy, I certainly wouldn't write it that way, but does that make it grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The subject *many* of the interrogative subordinate clause is plural; hence, we use *are*.

> a count of [how many of this item **are** in the room]

Comment: Thanks, @Sam.  I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I see now I was confused as to whether "of this item" would alter the plurality, as in "this item is in the room" vs "these items are in the room".

Answer (score 1):

You use 'many' to discuss **countable** items and a plural verb, e.g. I wonder how many people/cats/books/chairs **are** in the room.

If you were discussing a **non-countable** amount or quantity, you would use 'much' and a singular verb, e.g. *how much air is in the room, how much water is in the bath, how much coal is in the sack*.

> Many is used to describe count nouns or nouns that can be counted like
> books, ideas, leaves, and shoes. When using many, **the noun [and verb]  will always be plural.**
> (Britannica Dictionary)

[Much, Many, Count Nouns, and Mass Nouns](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/Much-Many-Count-Nouns-and-Mass-Nouns#:%7E:text=When%20using%20much%2C%20the%20noun,much%20and%20many%20are%20used.)

Comment: @Sam - that is true, but not relevant.

Comment: @Sam - is that better?

Comment: @Sam - Why **did you use** three question marks?

Comment: @Sam - it seems odd to criticise another's poor sentence construction, while perpetrating one of the most annoying errors possible in that field.

Comment: Just trying to make you notice it (nothing else is in my mind).

Comment: @Sam - multiple exclamation or question marks (or a mixture) are often seen as rudely and greedily attempting to grab the reader's attention, as you have just illustrated.

Comment: That's was not my intention, I was just trying to make you notice the error because you are so experienced. (I also had a doubt as I am a learner)